# Assembler invert XMM register

Tags: assembly, sse, bitwise-not

I have to invert the contents of a 128-bit XMM register.

I've tried it in many different ways, but all I get is a not-so-nice error message.

I'm thankful for all kinds of help.

Comment: What do you mean by "invert"? Complement it? Reverse bits? Reverse bytes? And what is the error

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Only one of those things is commonly called "inverting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `PCMPEQD` on some register (passing it as both operands) to load all ones into it.
Then, `PXOR` that register with the input register.